# Trouble scraping data using rvest

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

Please I am trying to scrape data off of google news website. I want to extract the keywords of trending topics on the site using the rvest and dplyr packages, and selector gadget on google chrome. Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
google.news<-read_html("https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-NG&gl=NG&ceid=NG:en")
google.news %>%
+html_nodes(".boy4he") %>%
+html_text()
```

But after running the code, I get the following error message:

```
google.news<-read_html("https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-NG&gl=NG&ceid=NG:en")
> google.news %>%
+ +html_nodes(".boy4he") %>%
+ +html_text()
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Please what could be wrong? I would appreciate anybody's advice or suggestions, thanks.

Comment: You have typos in your code, probably as a result of a copy+paste. Remove the `+` from before the `html_nodes`and `html_text`.  This results in an empty character vector, but that's another problem (the site is probably dinamically built, and I think scraping Google news is agains ToS)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice; I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
google.news<-read_html("https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-NG&gl=NG&ceid=NG:en")

google.news %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".boy4he") %>%
  html_attr("aria-label")

[1] "Godwin Obaseki"            "Abdullahi Umar Ganduje"    "Sanusi Lamido Sanusi"      "Zamfara"                  
 [5] "All Progressives Congress" "Dangote Group"             "Kano"                      "Senate of Nigeria"        
 [9] "Aliko Dangote"             "Muhammadu Buhari"
```

The values are "hidden" in the html attribute "aria-label":

```
<a class="boy4he" href="./topics/CAAqJQgKIh9DQkFTRVFvTEwyMHZNREV5YlRKa2RHd1NBbVZ1S0FBUAE?hl=en-NG&amp;gl=NG&amp;ceid=NG%3Aen" aria-label="Abdullahi Umar Ganduje"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dominik, the code works. That means I will have to always dive into the source code of the webpage I want to scrape data off of to find the html attribute or tag.

Comment: You're welcome! The simplest way to find the html tag/css selector is to use the css selector gadget extension for the chrome browser. But in your case this would just tell you the css selector (".boy4he"), so you still need to dig into the source code. But selector gadget works 90% of time. Consider upvoting/accepting my answer if it helped you.